# Facebook og fix to display just one thumbnail in sharer.php

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-sharer

I want to share a video with a thumbnail of only one image via sharer.php

I understand that most of people use Feed dialog with flexible UI but I need advanced options in this case.

A dialog looks like this and I want to have only one thumbnail the on I specify with `og:image` on a relative page

[image]

My OG tags look like this:

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="*admins*" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="*app_id*" />

<meta property="og:type" content="movie" /> 
<meta property="og:video:height" content="*height*" /> 
<meta property="og:video:width" content="*width*" /> 
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
<meta property="og:title" content="*title*" /> 
<meta property="og:description" content="*description*" />
<meta property="og:image" content="*image*" /> 
<meta property="og:url" content="*url*" />
<meta property="og:video" content="*video*" />
```

And I use a basic function to call a **Share This Link** dialog

```
u = $(*link*).html();
t = $(*name*).html();
window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(u)+'&t='+encodeURIComponent(t),'sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=*width*,height=*height*');
return false;
```

My question is how can I modify my code / add code to have only 1 thumbnail instead of `1 of 2` message

I tried changing my code, removing og:url, checking og:image, etc, using facebook debugger to clear its cache. And I could find nothing on net either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been told you have to modify the code in (meta property="og:image" content="*image*" /) to
(meta property="og:image" content="http://www.yoursite.location of the image" /)

I've personally messed with this for several days and finally accomplished it!  The way I did it was to publish the image I wanted FB to use for my site to my server.  Then, in my browser, I did a right-click on the newly published image and chose "Copy image location".  Then I added the above code to my page html between the header tags, and **pasted the copied image location** between the quotes.  Be sure that your image is at least 200 x 200 px - they say the bigger the better, but not more that 5MB in size.  I was having a lot of trouble getting FB to pick my specified image because I was making it too small.  I've finally gotten success just now by resizing my image to 1000x712, and it's working.

In my case, Facebook has still not recognized my specified image as the ONLY image I want used, but I've also been told that FB will "scrape" my site every 24 hours and, hopefully, once that's done, the multiple images option will disappear.  Hope this helps.